# Is there a single word to describe the loss of a sibling?

Tags: word-choice

Is there a single word to describe the loss of a sibling?

Without a proper name it is hard for the grief to be acknowledged.

Comment: It's a [bereavement](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/bereavement). English doesn't have a special word for loss of a sibling as distinct from any other family member or close friend.

Comment: Do you know of a single word for the loss of any other particular relation? Why does the lack of a single word make it hard to acknowledge...why can't it be acknowledged with your title description?

Comment: Sure, if the reason you lost your sibling is you murdered your sibling, in which case the single word is "fratricide."

Answer (score 3):

No there isn't.

You wrote `"Without a proper name it is hard for the grief to be acknowledged"`

"loss of a sibling" should be more than enough for someone to acknowledge the grief, even to those without siblings themselves.

You have only asked for a word to describe the situation which means there is a chance that you yourself have lost a sibling, and that is enough for me to feel a deep sense of remorse. So as I said, simply stating that you have lost a sibling should be more than enough.

There is a word (which is to be used loosely as a transposition from the animal kingdom) for the killing of one's sibling: **Siblicide**.

More specifically **Fratricide** for the killing of a brother and **Sororicide** for the killing of a sister.

Unfortunately there isn't a word for the loss of a sibling although now that you have mentioned it, I feel as though it would be a good idea to have one.

If it is indeed the case that you have lost a sibling then I wish you all the best and I have no doubt everyone else reading your question shares the sentiment.

Comment: OED restricts *siblicide* to the action of young birds in a nest: I don't believe there is a term for the human equivalent.

Comment: Siblicide has been observed in other animal species such as amphibians and mammals. For example Oxford dictionary defines: 'the killing of a sibling or siblings, as a behaviour pattern typical in various animal groups.'. It would be fine to transpose this definition to humans as we do with many things to describe a situation. I agree that it is most common within species of birds.

Comment: In the pshyco-medical world the term is used with human beings in mind. I have seen the term used to describe the deadly rivalry observed between royal siblings throughout history.

Comment: Fratricide can mean killing your brother or sister according to Merriam-Webster but this sort of usage (where male is taken as general) is frowned upon these days as belittling women. https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fratricide